# Como obtener la cantidad de veces que se repite una palabra en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

como puedo obtener la cantidad de veces que se repite la palabra "false", en una columna desde mysql.

ejemplo:

```
id |  read  |
-------------
1  | false  |
-------------
2  | true   |
-------------
3  | false  |
-------------
4  | false  |
-------------
```

**total = 3 veces**

Yo trate de hacer la consulta asi:

```
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT 
(length(read)-length(replace(read ,'false','')))/5 as COUNT   
FROM  ge_mensajes_col");

    $cant = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    $json = '{"newMSJ": [';

        $char ='"';

        $json .= 
        '{
            "total":"'.$query.'"
        },';    

    // buat menghilangkan koma diakhir array
    $json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);
    $json .= ']}';
    // print json
    echo $json; 
    mysqli_close($connect);
```

Pero no me funciona no obtengo la cantidad en el Json me muestra vacio.

Answer (score 6):

> Desde la consola de **MySQL**, para obtener la cantidad de veces que la
>   palabra `false` se esta repitiendo bastaría con que hagas lo siguiente

```
SELECT COUNT(read) AS Total 
FROM nombreTabla
WHERE read = 'false';
```

1. Lo que hice fue que a la función de agregación `COUNT()` le pase el nombre de la columna donde necesito que se haga el conteo.
2. Posterior para que solo me devuelva cuantas veces se repite la palabra false, hago uso de un `WHERE` al final donde le indico que solo haga el conteo donde la palabra sea igual a false

Te dejo este ejemplo funcional donde te pongo en práctica la teoría que te explique

[ENLACE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2ada81cd247bc15b633d75af552aebe)

¿Cómo trabaja la función de agregación `COUNT()`?

> La función de agregación `COUNT()` te va a retornar el número total de
>   filas que cumplen una determinada condición

Comment: Hola alfredo, que pena contigo y abajo en la parte donde debo imprimirla como hago?, pq estoy haciendolo asi pero no muestra nada `"total":"'.$query.'"`, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres contarlas todas en una única consulta prueba así:

```
SELECT `reader`, COUNT(`reader`) 
FROM ge_mensajes_col
GROUP BY `reader`
```

El "GROUP BY" ayuda a agrupar los registros de una columna, en este caso agrupa por `reader`.

Comment: pero por que debe agrupar? si solo quiere saber la cantidad de veces que existe la palabra false?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, ya estaba la respuesta pero vi una opcion de agregar algo más.

Answer (score 1):

Esta solución es muy simple y te ayudará a contar las filas que contienen la palabra `false` en la columna `read` veo que estás utilizando php Entonces sería utilizando `mysqli_num_rows` para obtener las filas que cumplan con la condición `WHERE read LIKE '%false%'`

```
$sql = "SELECT read FROM ge_mensajes_col WHERE read LIKE '%false%'   ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo mysqli_num_rows($result)
```